# Does chrome have public APIs for appcache, formData etc to be used in extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, html5-appcache

Chrome has 
`browsingData` permission has the api to remove `appcache, cache, formData, indexedDB, passwords, pluginData, serverBoundCertificates, service workers, webSQL,`

However, I wonder, if there are public API's to query the data stored or check the amount of data present in various kinds of storages provided above.

Comment: No, there's no [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) for that. But extensions can open any site in an iframe where the content script will have access to that site's IndexedDB, WebSQL and other standard DOM stuff.

Comment: You mean there is no public API for that?
Chrome internally remove various types of such data.